# Mostrar el total de columnas de un csv

Tags: linux, bash

Estoy realizando un ejercicio que me pide mostrar el total de filas y columnas que contiene un csv.

Consigo mostrar las filas con el siguiente comando:

```
wc -l dataset_lol.csv
```

Pero no encuentro la forma de hacer que me devuelva el numero de columnas. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo con wc, o algún otro comando?

Comment: ¿Podrías poner algún ejemplo de entrada con su salida deseada? ¿Tienen todas las filas el mismo número de columnas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
head -1 myfile.csv | sed 's/[^,]//g' | wc -c
```

Donde, suponiendo que *myfile.csv* **sea tu archivo** `.csv` y contenga, por ejemplo, lo siguiente:

```
1,2,3,4,5
a,b,c,d,e
a,b,c,d,e
```

Con `head -1 myfile.csv`, conseguirías la primera línea. Poniendo por ejemplo, -2, leerías la segunda línea y así sucesivamente.

Quedando así:
`1,2,3,4,5`

Con `sed 's/[^,]//g'`, se consigue eliminar las comas para que no influyan en el resultado.

Por último, utilizando `wc -c` te contará el número de caracteres; puesto detrás de los comandos anteriores, te leerá el número de caracteres de esa línea; es decir, las columnas.

**En tu caso, por tanto, sería algo así:**

```
head -1 dataset_lol.csv | sed 's/[^,]//g' | wc -c
```

Answer (score 1):

La manera más sencilla que se me viene a la mente es usar `awk`.

Por ejemplo, teniendo un archivo así:

```
Columna1, Columna2, Columna3, col4, col5
row1, 123, 123.89,r,2.3
row2, 456, 321.89,s,0.1
```

Usamos esto:

```
$ awk -F, '{print NF;exit}' archivo.txt
5
```

Donde `-F,` indica que el delimitador serán las comas, y `NF` es la cantidad de campos según el delimitador.

Ya después de conocer estos datos, nos salimos con `exit` la primera vez que los conozcamos, para evitar traer más datos al buffer.

Un ejemplo rápido sin usar un archivo:

```
$ echo "1,2,3,4,5" | awk -F, '{print NF; exit}'
5
```

Todo esto es suponiendo que el header del documento tiene la cantidad de columnas requeridas.